# I can't see my data in graph with shinken and graphite

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphite

Apache 2.4.7, 
 
Ubuntu Server 14.04.
Shinken with WebUI
 
Name Server : dev03

I'm on an Ubuntu Server 14, I've installed Shinken to make monitoring. Shinken is working good and discover hosts on my network.
Then I want to "link" graphite on Shinken to have some graphics. All the install works fine and I can see the Graphite UI on my server. I follow this tutorial to make install of Graphite : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-graphite-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

But I've some problems :

1. My Graphite doesn't display data when I make something like :

   echo "test.count 4 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003

Nothing appears on Graphite...

2. When I go to Shinken, the windows of graph display `no data`. Certainly due to the first problem.
3. And when I click on `Show more button` he sends me on the page of Graphite, but with nothing else behind uri. (like http://dev03) Is it normal ?

I've trying this also :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/509629/sending-data-to-port-does-not-seem-to-be-working-on-ubuntu-linux

But it seems my port 2003 is not listening / open

```
 netstat -tuplen
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7767            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       544010      1816/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7768            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       542859      1194/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        9068        931/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7769            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543251      1432/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7771            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543079      1317/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7772            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543634      1579/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7773            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543810      1694/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44255         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543623      1582/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43007         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       542845      1201/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38856         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543911      1793/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57546         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543808      1695/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46282         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543238      1439/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        9099        855/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8098        548/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34293         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543071      1326/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8930        792/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      107        9067        931/postgres
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7770                :::*                    LISTEN      1001       543920      1792/python
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          8101        548/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          541053      708/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8932        792/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:703             0.0.0.0:*                           0          8097        548/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          8092        548/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::703                  :::*                                0          8100        548/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          8099        548/rpcbind
```

If someone can help me... because I've see many forums and other website, but I can't find a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I allow myself to answer my own question, because I noticed that there was not a lot of answers / aids on Graphite / Shinken.  And personally I struggled to find a solution.

So, when I launch this command, on my Ubuntu server :

```
service carbon-cache start
```

It seems that carbon-cache doesn't start... or not as expected. I found another way to start this service and be sure it works :

```
carbon-cache --config /etc/carbon/carbon.conf start # For normal mode
carbon-cache --config /etc/carbon/carbon.conf --debug start # For debug mode
```

That's only way for me to start this daemon correctly. In fact my port 2003 was listening as attempt. After that, Shinken and Graphite works fine.

(It seems on Debian, there is no this problem. I encounter this only on Ubuntu Server)